# Как объединить два массива PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется следующий массив:

```
Array ( [0] => Гамбургер [1] => Чизбургер [2] => Классический бургер )
Array ( [0] => 100rub [1] => 300rub [2] => 500rub )
```

как его правильно объединить чтобы получился:

```
Array (

Array (
title => Гамбургер
price => 100rub
)
Array (
title => Чизбургер
price => 300rub
)
...
)
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php в документации есть нужный вам пример кода. Либо просто циклом пробегитесь по массиву)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```
$array1 = [
    'Гамбургер',
    'Чизбургер',
    'Классический бургер',
    '...'
];

$array2 = [
    '100rub',
    '300rub',
    '500rub',
    '...'
];

$array3 = array_combine($array1,$array2 );
foreach ($array3 as $key=>$value) {
    $menu = [];
    $menu[] = ['title' =>$key, 'price' => $value];
    var_dump($menu);
}
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Гамбургер
            [price] => 100rub
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Чизбургер
            [price] => 300rub
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Классический бургер
            [price] => 500rub
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => ...
            [price] => ...
        )

)
```